# URQL Graphcache updateQuery with pagination

Tags: javascript, graphql, urql

I'm using URQL to query (`UserItemsQuery`) a list of items, and to create new items (`CreateItem`). These items belong to a user.

In normal circumstances, I would use `updateQuery` to add the newly created item that is returned from `createItem` to the cache:

```
Mutation: {
  createItem(result, { params: { userId } }, cache) {
    cache.updateQuery(
      {
        query: UserItemsQuery,
        variables: { id: userId },
      },
      (data) => {
        if (!data) return null
        data.user.items.nodes.push(result.createItem.item)
        return data
      }
    )
  },
```

However, the query to `userItemsQuery` is paginated:

```
resolvers: {
  User: {
    chatMessages: relayPagination(),
  }, 
},
```

**So in order to use `updateQuery`, I need to know the pagination details for the last query to `UserItemsQuery` so I can re-query with the correct pagination. How can I access those params?**